# Compute sum of sine waves in numpy; avoid large matrices while maintaining numpy performance

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm currently trying to compute the sum multiple generated sine waves, generated like so:

`np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * np.arange(N) / SAMPLE_RATE)`

where `N` is the number of samples I want to generate, and `SAMPLE_RATE` is the sample rate in Hz. One neat thing I realized is that if I pass in a column vector for `freq`, it'll generate a matrix of samples due to broadcasting, where each row corresponds to a single sine wave for a single frequency, and each column corresponds to a single sample point for each frequency. As an example:

```py
freq = np.array([[1,2,3,4]]).T
SAMPLE_RATE = 1
N = 5
print(np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * np.arange(N) / 20))
```

outputs

```
[[ 0.          0.30901699  0.58778525  0.80901699  0.95105652]
 [ 0.          0.58778525  0.95105652  0.95105652  0.58778525]
 [ 0.          0.80901699  0.95105652  0.30901699 -0.58778525]
 [ 0.          0.95105652  0.58778525 -0.58778525 -0.95105652]]
```

which if summed along the 0 axis, yields the sum of all of the sine waves. However, this takes up `O(N * len(freq))` space, which when N and freq are large is unacceptable. Would there be a way to do this in `O(N)` space without sacrificing on the vectorized summation at the end? This problem should generalize to if a matrix is generated through any broadcasting operation only to immediately be collapsed by summation.

Comment: Write your own code with something like `numba`.  The trade off you describe is the cost of working with a limited set of standard tools.

Comment: if `freq` is monotonic there may be some fourier or taylor series expansion that will help, but that's more a question for a [math.se] stack - just pulled out my old books on it and my eyes glazed over.

Answer (score 0):

OK, found it on the math stack [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544608/how-can-i-express-the-sum-of-sin-a-sin2a-sin3a-cdots-sinn-1a/544621)

As long as `freq` is of the form `np.arange(m) + 1` (in this case m=4)

```
s = lambda x, m: np.sin(np.pi * m * x / 20)

f = lambda x, m: np.where(x == 0, 0, s(x, m + 1) * s(x, m) / s(x, 1))  
                 # ^^^ to fix divide by zero error at 0

f(np.arange(N), 4)
Out[]: 
array([0.00000000e+00, 2.65687576e+00, 3.07768354e+00, 1.48130525e+00,
       1.22464680e-16])

np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * np.arange(N) / 20).sum(0)
Out[]: 
array([0.00000000e+00, 2.65687576e+00, 3.07768354e+00, 1.48130525e+00,
       1.11022302e-16])
```

You'll get floating-point differences when it's very close to zero (as with the last point there) but it should otherwise work.